# Swift: How do I cast a Character as a String to do a simple compare?

Tags: xcode, string, swift, compare, character

I am getting the error at the "==" in code 
 Cannot invoke '==' with an argument list of type '(@lvalue String, @lvalue Character)'

--------representation of my code

```
var randomWord = "horse"
var guessLetter = "g"

for var charIndex = 0; charIndex < countElements(randomWord); charIndex++ {
    var index = advance(str.startIndex, charIndex)
    var oneLetter = str[index]

    if guessLetter == oneLetter {
        println("ok")
    } else {
        println("nope")
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3386109 `var guessLetter = 'g'` isn't valid in Swift.

Comment: In case you're not aware, if you need to iterate a string, you don't need to do it with an integer and then use `advance`, you can just write `for oneLetter in randomWord { if oneLetter == guessLetter etc... } `.  If you also want an incrementing number alongside it, you can do `for (i, oneLetter) in enumerate(randomWord)`.

Answer (score 2):

One very simple way is to use [string interpolation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html):

```
if guessLetter == "\(oneLetter)"
```

Another is to have guessLetter be a Character:

```
var guessLetter: Character = "g"
```

Comment: ... or `if guessLetter == String(oneLetter)`

Comment: @DavidPeterson You're welcome. Whenever you get the answer you're looking for click the checkmark to the left to accept it.